# Redis Command To Sort Keys

Tags: javascript, php, sorting, redis

The Redis command **keys *** will return a list of all keys and **scan 0** is a more recent way to do something similar, but with less blocking. Do any commands exist that can sort the keys found, such as alphabetically, numerically, by creation timestamp, etc.?

Example of standard and fancy command sought:

standard **keys post:*** command:

```
post:2150
post:2400
post:1001
post:1006
```

**fancy command** to sort the keys alphabetically:

```
post:1001
post:1006
post:2150
post:2400
```

Comment: Are you looking for [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Redis returns keys, using KEYS (don't use it in production!) or SCAN, unordered. There is no "fancy" API to return them sorted but you can do it in the client application.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this to be the case. I wasn't sure if I missed something in the Redis spec. Yes, that's what I am currently doing, sorting the results in the client.

Comment: Excellent - if you're doing a lot of these, you can consider moving (some)  the logic to Redis via the use of (Sorted) Sets, the SORT command and/or Lua scripts. OTOH, using Redis' too much RAM/CPU/NW can become another issue, so there's definitely a tradeoff. Personally, if you only need to sort the keys for the client, I'd keep that work there (unless the client's performance is an issue ;))

Comment: Completely agree on the client offload and am totally leveraging the z  commands for shuffling data by score. I don't work for Redis, but have to say its features are a whole new architectural paradigm and it's a game changer.

Comment: if you need a specific one time thing, you can run the unix command to sort output of `SCAN`

Answer (score 13):

You can always use your unix commands which works perfectly

`redis-cli --scan --pattern yourpattern* | sort`

Answer (score 1):

For completeness sake:

You technically can do this within the context of Redis, using the `EVAL` command.

This would get all keys according to the `post:*` pattern, then sort the keys, and use them to `MGET` all the items.

```
EVAL "local keys = redis.call('KEYS','post:*');
      if (table.getn(keys) == 0) then return {} end;
      table.sort(keys);
      return redis.call('MGET',unpack(keys));"
```

This approach can increase performance, but manipulating Redis using LUA scripts might feel inelegant.

There are also issues with the `KEYS` command, and some safety considerations with `EVAL` of course.

I would say that the "Proper Redis Way" to solve this, would be to design a "composite data structure" around the use case:

```
// a scoreless sorted set can be used as an index
SET post:1500 <value>
ZADD posts_index 0 post:1500

// Whenever you need a sorted (range) of items, you first check the index 
ZRANGE posts_index - + BYLEX 
ZRANGE posts_index [posts:1000 (posts:2000 BYLEX
```

The sorted set `posts_index` is just a set of all the keys in the `post` "namespace". Of course, if you set TTLs or remove items from cache, you will need to manage this for the `posts_index` set as well.

The result of `ZRANGE` is sorted, and can be used to `GET`/`MGET` items

The advantage of this over client-side sorting is performance: It's pre-sorted, and you can split it into ranges, use cursors to only hold a few items in memory at a time, etc.